# I am a bit new to html how would I space the images?

Tags: html, css

Screenshot: https://i.ibb.co/NN1kF97/Screenshot-20210417-005957.png

Not sure on how to space out the images I am a bit new to html tbh

```
<section class="section--primary--light text--center">
  <div class="container">
      <h3>GitHub repositories used to make this possible/credit :) </h3>
      <a href="https://github.com/martymcmodding/qUINT/tree/master/Shaders">
        <img align="center" src="https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api/pin/?username=martymcmodding&repo=qUINT&theme=dark"/>
      </a>
      <a href="https://github.com/crosire/reshade-shaders/tree/master/Shaders">
        <img align="center" src="https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api/pin/?username=crosire&repo=reshade-shaders&theme=dark"/>
      </a>
      <a href="https://github.com/prod80/prod80-ReShade-Repository">
        <img align="center" src="https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api/pin/?username=prod80&repo=prod80-ReShade-Repository&theme=dark"/>
      </a>
      <a href="https://github.com/prod80/prod80-ReShade-Repository">
        <img align="center" src="https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api/pin/?username=prod80&repo=prod80-ReShade-Repository&theme=dark"/>
      </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Easiest and fastest for an absolute beginner would be adding [padding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding) or [margins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin).

Answer (score 0):

Use margin property to space out elements.

Padding will also be useful in your case as mentioned by @AlexanderNied.

```css
a {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section class="section--primary--light text--center">
  <div class="container">
      <h3>GitHub repositories used to make this possible/credit :) </h3>
      <a href="https://github.com/martymcmodding/qUINT/tree/master/Shaders">
        <img align="center" src="https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api/pin/?username=martymcmodding&repo=qUINT&theme=dark"/>
      </a>
      <a href="https://github.com/crosire/reshade-shaders/tree/master/Shaders">
        <img align="center" src="https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api/pin/?username=crosire&repo=reshade-shaders&theme=dark"/>
      </a>
      <a href="https://github.com/prod80/prod80-ReShade-Repository">
        <img align="center" src="https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api/pin/?username=prod80&repo=prod80-ReShade-Repository&theme=dark"/>
      </a>
      <a href="https://github.com/prod80/prod80-ReShade-Repository">
        <img align="center" src="https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api/pin/?username=prod80&repo=prod80-ReShade-Repository&theme=dark"/>
      </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `margin` add spacing. For `margin` there is also `margin-left`, `margin-right`, etc, if you want the spacing to be set to top, left, right, or bottom of the **element(img in this case)** you attach it to.

I also added flex to your `container` **class** and so you got two **elements** per row. If you wanted it to look like the image you linked.

```css
img {
  width: 100%
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container > a {
  flex: 50%; /* or - flex: 0 50% - or - flex-basis: 50% - */
  /*demo*/
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section class="section--primary--light text--center">
  <div class="container">
      <h3>GitHub repositories used to make this possible/credit :) </h3>
      <a href="https://github.com/martymcmodding/qUINT/tree/master/Shaders">
        <img align="center" src="https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api/pin/?username=martymcmodding&repo=qUINT&theme=dark"/>
      </a>
      <a href="https://github.com/crosire/reshade-shaders/tree/master/Shaders">
        <img align="center" src="https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api/pin/?username=crosire&repo=reshade-shaders&theme=dark"/>
      </a>
      <a href="https://github.com/prod80/prod80-ReShade-Repository">
        <img align="center" src="https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api/pin/?username=prod80&repo=prod80-ReShade-Repository&theme=dark"/>
      </a>
      <a href="https://github.com/prod80/prod80-ReShade-Repository">
        <img align="center" src="https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api/pin/?username=prod80&repo=prod80-ReShade-Repository&theme=dark"/>
      </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

```
  <a href="https://github.com/crosire/reshade-shaders/tree/master/Shaders">
    <img align="center" src="https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api/pin/?username=crosire&repo=reshade-shaders&theme=dark"/>
  </a>
  <a href="https://github.com/prod80/prod80-ReShade-Repository">
    <img align="center" src="https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api/pin/?username=prod80&repo=prod80-ReShade-Repository&theme=dark"/>
  </a>
  <a href="https://github.com/prod80/prod80-ReShade-Repository">
    <img align="center" src="https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api/pin/?username=prod80&repo=prod80-ReShade-Repository&theme=dark"/>
  </a>
```